# Rails 6 proper rescue from error and fetch error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, monads

In my Rails 6 app I want to handle the situation where the external API returns me an error and I passed it to the Failure method (it's a [dry-monad method](https://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-monads/1.3/result/)).

```
def call
  response = api.check_applicant_status(id: applicant_id, options: options)
rescue Errors::BadRequestError => e
  e.message

  result(response: response, error: e.message)
end

attr_reader :applicant_id

private

def result(response:, error:)
  if response.present?
    Success(response)
  else
    Failure(error)
  end
end
```

The above code will only work if an error occurs. In happy path (where there will be proper response) the whole class will return a result from `response` variable (a hash) and won't even touch the `result` method.

I think the `rescue` should be at the end of each method (that's the convention I guess) but in my case it will give an error of `undefined local variable or method 'e` in case of happy path.

What is the right way to pass an error message to Failure in case of an error and to pass the result (hash) to Success in case of a happy path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need the private method? Assume success unless you rescue, then assume error right?

```
def call
  response = api.check_applicant_status(id: applicant_id, options: options)
  Success(response)
rescue Errors::BadRequestError => e
  Failure(e.message)
end
```

Comment: I get your point and it will work but what if I have this piece of code in my app 10 times? that's why I wanted to extract this thing to a private method (it should be `protected` btw) - to be used by more than one class.

Comment: @mr_muscle in that case the logic can easily be moved to said protected method. If you're duplicating code, you're not practicing DRY anyway.